# lists:any true in false cases?

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

I run the following anonymous function and variables in the interpreter, and get wrongly so a true statement, but why is that, and what do I need to change:

```
Lst = [1,2,3].
Y = 52.
lists:any(fun(Y) -> lists:member(Y, Lst) end, Lst).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the `Y` in the argument list of the `fun` shadows the outer definition of `Y`.  It therefore checks if any list element is a member of the list, which is always true.

You don't actually need `lists:any` here; you can call `lists:member` directly, without `lists:any`:

```
> lists:member(Y, Lst).
false
```

The equivalent using `lists:any` would be:

```
> lists:any(fun(X) -> X =:= Y end, Lst).             
false
```

Here, the argument is `X`, so we can access `Y` from outside the fun.

Comment: Actually it got me thinking. What part of the code snippet construction is responsible for the shadowing. Is it the lists:any(...), or the lists:member(...). And why is it the case that it is shadowing. Does it have to do with how arguments are passed to anonymous functions?

Comment: It's the `fun` itself. Any variables in the argument list shadow variables outside the `fun`.